# Generating UUIDs for IndexedDB keys?

Tags: javascript, html, uuid, indexeddb

The W3C spec for IndexedDB defines [a key generator](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#dfn-key-generator) as:

> A key generator generates a monotonically increasing numbers [sic] every time a key is needed.

Now, it seems (to me) that a common use case for IndexedDB (or, for that matter, any of the HTML5 client-side storage options: WebSQL, localStorage etc.) would be apps designed to work offline (in conjunction with HTML5 ApplicationCache).

In this scenario, a *disconnected* web application might generate new objects/records in it's local data store that are later synced to a centralised database when a connection to the server becomes available.

Further, any application where multiple clients sync to the *same* centralised database typically requires a mechanism to prevent ID collisions.

UUID (or GUID) is a good choice, as it enables unique key generation without any central coordination. By contrast, *"monotonically incrementing numbers"* is a poor solution (unless each client is "seeded" with a starting value that is unlikely to collide with other users).

I find it surprising that the IndexedDB spec does not specify (or even allow for future support of) alternate key generators, such as a UUID generator. Some may suggest that the answer is simply not to use IndexedDB's builtin key generator at all, instead have your application generate it's own keys.

However, while there are plenty of Javascript-based UUID generators available, many of them seem to be based on Math.random() which has known limitations in terms of it's *randomness*, so might not be a good choice if absolute unique keys must be guaranteed.

A native UUID generator provided by the IndexedDB implementors would (presumably) be more robust and perform better than a script implemented/imported by the application; one would think.

So am I missing something here, or is this a missed opportunity by the W3C IndexedDB working group?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty charged question but, if you want my thoughts on it after working with IndexedDB for a couple years, I'd say that a UUID API would be nice but it seems beyond scope of what the working group is trying to achieve.

A UUID is, eponymously, "universally" unique. The highest concept of uniqueness in IndexedDB is the object store, at the data level and the database at the browser level.

In practice, I like that I can get predictable, repeatable results when re-running code on a fresh database or object store. Although I can see situations where I would want to maintain uniqueness across all client dbs, I definitely wouldn't want it to be the default.

I personally don't require universal uniqueness with my clientside databases, but, in any case, there are great UUID JS implementations available if you do.

Answer (score 0):

The objectStore keys are meant to be unique to the objectStore in the local database, and nothing else. Any higher level semantics about uniqueness are really beyond the scope of IndexedDB. You describe UUID, but even that is just one form of unique keys.  There are lots of different ways to generate a UUID that have different properties, including a specific prefix combined with monotonically increasing lower-bits, randomly generating the whole thing, scoping it by ethernet card address, etc.

By picking something that is only scoped to the local instance, IDB (for better or worse) forces developers to make a careful choice about a "globally" unique key.