# Get key of added record in IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexeddb

I have this code in IndexedDB:

```
var request = objectStore.add({ entryType: entryType, entryDate: t});
```

Now I want to know the key of this record that was just added in. How do I do that?

I found [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg679063.aspx), and this
code:

```
var data = {"bookName" : "Name", "price" : 100, "rating":"good"};
var request = objectStore.add(data);
request.onsuccess = function(event){
    document.write("Saved with id ", event.result)
    var key = event.result;
};
```

This does not work for me - key shows up as undefined. I think I am missing something basic here!

Comment: I should think there is some documentation for IndexedDB - is there no information on this there?

Comment: I could not find it - any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Go through this code

```
var data = {"bookName" : "Name", "price" : 100, "rating":"good"};
var request = objectStore.add(data);
request.onsuccess = function(event){
    document.write("Saved with id ", event.result)
    var key = event.target.result;
};
```

Hope this code will work to retrieve key of last inserted Record

Answer (score 5):

The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/) is written for user agent, not for developer. So it is confusing. Key generator is provided by the user agent.

Any `event` object that is received by `onsuccess` handler always have `event.target.result`. It is the key you are looking for. The key is auto generated if you don't provide it, assuming you set autoIncrement to true.

It is [documented](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#dfn-steps-for-storing-a-record-into-an-object-store) in Step 8: as follow:

> 1. The result of this algorithm is key.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `idb` Promise wrapper for IndexedDB then the new key is just the return value from the `add()` call:

```
import { openDB } from 'idb';

const db = await openDB(...);
const tx = db.transaction('mystore', 'readwrite');
const newId = await tx.store.add({ hello: 'world' });
await tx.done;

console.log(`Autogenerated unique key for new object is ${newId}`);
```

Remember of course, this will only work if you include `autoIncrement: true` in the options passed to `createObjectStore()`.

Answer (score -1):

The trick here is knowing how to search using phrases iteratively, until you land on what you need. I've never heard of IndexedDB before, but seem to have found what you want.

I put ["IndexedDB" into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=indexeddb) and found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB#Using_an_index). That yielded the phrase "key generator", so I [searched for that as well](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=indexeddb+key+generator) which led me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107689/generating-uuids-for-indexeddb-keys) and [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#dfn-key-generator).

The StackOverflow link discusses using UUIDs, which of course can be generated in JavaScript, and the last link appears to have examples to do what you want out of the box.