# Adding a record and retrieving the key generated

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, indexeddb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get key of added record in IndexedDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068171/get-key-of-added-record-in-indexeddb)

I asked this question here: [Get key of added record in IndexedDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068171/get-key-of-added-record) but I dont know why it was downvoted. I have spent a significant amount of time looking into this now.

Here is the code to add the record

```
var request = objectStore.put({ entryType: entryType, entryDate: t });
        request.onsuccess = function (event) {
            console.log("Saved with id ", evt.result)
            var key = evt.result;
        };
```

However, the key value shows up as undefined. I read only this article that talks about getting a key right after the transaction http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg679063.aspx. I have not been able to find anything else. I think I am missing something basic here.. ?

Comment: ok - f#$k it. i went with generating my own id. indexeddb can be a bitch sometimes

Comment: How did you define the store that you were placing it in? Did you tell it to autogenerate the key?

Comment: Thanks for cross-referencing your old question - that's helpful to ensure people don't duplicate effort. Nevertheless, duplicating questions isn't generally a good idea. It is better to improve the old one where possible. I suspect your previous question was downvoted as it didn't appear to contain evidence of prior research, which seems to be a solid requirement here! `:)`

Comment: Improve your old questions. Don't feel bad about down voting. Just improve your question. Don't post duplicate question.